# passar vários parâmetros no ireport

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, ireport

Estou com o seguinte problema: criei no java um `selectcheckbox`, onde a pessoa vai selecionar vários objetos; quando envio para o `managed bean`, consigo receber esses objetos listados. Agora quero enviar como parâmetro para o `ireport` para ele gerar um relatório com as informações que foram selecionadas.

Nos outros métodos uso o seguinte:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("codigo", agencias.getId());

    JasperImpressao jp = new JasperImpressao();

    jp.imprimirRelatorioPdf(parameters, "agencia.jasper");
```

Esse "jp.imprimirRelatorioPdf" faz tudo; se eu utilizar código ele imprime normal. Então pensei: lá no meu sql do `ireport`, em vez de usar o

```
WHERE agencias.`id` = $P{codigo}"
```

utilizar o

```
WHERE agencias.`id` IN $P{codigo}"
```

Então nesse parâmetro "codigo" eu passaria uma string com as id das agencias que quero imprimir: ficaria "where agencias in "1,2,3"

mas isso não funciona, dá erro de sintaxe.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from customer where $X{IN,customer_role,roles}`

Comment: Adriano, considere explicar sua resposta. Pode ser que para ti o código é de fácil entendimento, mas para outros, sem uma resposta com detalhes, é a mesma coisa que copiar e colar.

Answer (score 1):

verifique o tipo da variavel `$P{codigo}` no **jasper**, pra funcionar com o valor "1,2,3" dentro dela, ela deve ser do tipo *String*.

E para funcionar no **SQL** a sua string de consulta tem que ficar:

```
SELECT * FROM agencias WHERE agencias.id IN (1,2,3)
```